Delete event in mongoDB not return full document
I have this change event, in which i have created one handleDelete method but after delete on mongoDB it only gives that document Id but when i trying to fetch that document using this
const storyChangeStream = InProgressStory.watch();

    storyChangeStream.on("change", async (change) => {
        

        const handleDelete = async () => {
            console.log(change)
            try {
                const storyId = change.documentKey._id.toString();
                const deletedStory = await InProgressStory.findById(storyId).exec();

                console.log("hii hello")
                console.log(deletedStory)
                const authorId = deletedStory.authorId;
                if (userSockets[authorId]) {
                    io.to(userSockets[authorId]).emit("story_deleted", deletedStory);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error handling deleted story:", error);
            }
        };

        switch (change.operationType) {
            case "delete":
                await handleDelete();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });

I want to fetch autherId from that deleted document.
i already tried this
   const storyChangeStream = InProgressStory.watch([], { fullDocument: 'updateLookup' });
but returns only when any document change not working for delete event.

The delete has already been executed before you receive the changestream event telling you about it, so there is no document InProgressStory.findById(storyId).exec() to find.
If you enable changeStreamPreAndPostImages on the collection (requires MongoDB 6+), and set the fullDocumentBeforeChange option on the changesteam, the document prior to delete will be included in the change event.

Thanks for your suggestion i'll definitely try that. Currently I used one flag isDeleted.
